# Does unlocking the Necromancer trainer have any disadvantages?

Tags: battleheart-legacy

If you unlock the Necromancer trainer by

> taking the purple skull from the forbidden library, then visiting the mage tower
>  and responding in a friendly way to the necromancer that appears,

what are the consequences *apart* from unlocking the Necromancy trainer and making those skills available?

Are there any negative consequences due to the fact that

> you apparently killed the Headmaster at the mage tower under the influence of the skull?

Comment: It's also worth noting that there is a disadvantage to fighting the necromancer trainer, in that you can no longer obtain necromancer skills. Learned that the hard way. :(

Answer (score 4):

If you never unlock the Necromancer class, you will never gain access to the headmaster's chambers. As such, you're not missing out on any interactions with him. The only direct consequences are the following:

- Access to Necromancer skills (as stated in your question)
- Access to the Headmaster's chambers
- The fellow who had previously been guarding the Headmaster's room is permanently dead

**Spoiler 1:**

> There is a singular indirect consequence that depends on how you complete Rasmus's Spider Queen quest. If you use Necromancy in that fight, the students will think you're awesome and ask you to replace Rasmus. You basically get to accept a position at the Mage Academy, but this offers no benefits beyond enjoying some comical dialogue.

**Spoiler 2:**

> It is worth noting that if you even approach the skull you may be forced to take it with you. It requires a great deal of Charisma to resist the temptation to take the skull with you; I had to make several attempts (force-closing the app) with a Bard who had almost enough Charisma to learn all Bard skills.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't noticed any negative consequences during one play through.

Comment: I could have answered only "No", but I wanted to make sure that the answer was made within the context that I have only played through one time. There certainly could be alternate paths through the game that I was not exposed to, but nothing from my playthrough indicated that there were any repercussions. I don't need any clarification from the author.

Comment: Answers should be conclusive and definitive if at all possible. If you aren't sure, are guessing, or (in this case) can only offer anecdotal evidence, consider using comments to contribute instead.  :)